# Flash Media Live Encoder hardware/software compatibility/performance

Tags: flash, fmle

I am trying to improve the performance of FMLE and I am looking to buy appropriate hardware. I have searched all over but can't find a few simple answers:

1. Would FMLE appropriately be able to use a 2 processor system? (I am thinking of getting 2 Intel Xeon E5-2620 2.00GHz processors)
2. There is mention that FMLE can run on Windows Server 2003 (Web edition). What about the standard edition?
3. Is there any value to getting a graphics card to improve performance? My searches so far have indicated that Flash cannot use a GPU, which makes me think I can completely skip buying the graphics card.

Any ideas?

Thank you!